# How to combine two folders on github?

Tags: git, github

On my home directory, I have a folder called 'Templates'. On my github repo, for some reason, I have 'Templates' and also 'templates' and my home directory files are split between these two folders, even though they're in the same folder on my computer.

How can I combine 'templates' and 'Templates' on the github repo?

Answer (score 0):

Git is case sensitive.
Windows si not so you see a single folder but github is unix based so you see 2 folders.

What you need to do is simply to move your file to the desired folder. In order to do it you have to use `git mv` and not just `mv`.

`git mv` keep all the history so you will not lose anything.

```
git mv <source> <target>
```